# If one UIWebView consumes memory, other UIWebView from different controller goes blank

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, memory-management, uiwebview

I am having tab bar as my Launching View.

I am having three tabs in it. All the three tabs are having UIWebViews. 
Now, in the third tab, I do present a modalViewController, which is again having a UIWebView in it. If I try to watch youtube Videos in this fourth UIWebView, after some time, other Views from other tabs, goes blank.

Memory issue? Or Anything else?

I am wondering. Can you give me some pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of Presenting Modal ViewController, I used NavigationControllers in all three tabs, and pushed the Fourth View, and it seems to do the trick.